# LeetCode 534. Game Play Analysis III

Tags: sql

The following is the leetcode question

Table: **Activity**

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| player_id | int |
| device_id | int |
| event_date | date |
| games_played | int |

(player_id, event_date) is the primary key of this table.
This table shows the activity of players of some games.
Each row is a record of a player who logged in and played a number of games (possibly 0) before logging out on someday using some device.

Write an SQL query to report for each player and date, how many games played so far by the player. That is, the total number of games played by the player until that date. Check the example for clarity.

Return the result table in any order.

The query result format is in the following example.

| Player_Id | Device_ID | Event_Date | Games_Played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-03-01 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 2016-03-02 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 2017-06-25 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 2016-03-02 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 2018-07-03 | 5 |

I have solved it using the Windows function . My code is below

```
select player_id,event_date,sum(games_played) over(partition by player_id order by event_date) as games_played_so_far from activity
```

and the output

| player_id | event_date | games_played_So_Far |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-03-01 | 5 |
| 1 | 2016-05-02 | 11 |
| 1 | 2017-06-25 | 12 |
| 3 | 2016-03-02 | 0 |
| 3 | 2018-07-03 | 5 |

but on solving it using JOIN, I am not able to understand, why do we need to sum over a2.games_played and not a1.games_played. The code is below

```
SELECT a1.player_id, a1.event_date ,SUM(a2.games_played) AS games_played_so_far
FROM activity a1, activity a2
WHERE a1.player_id = a2.player_id
AND a1.event_date >=a2.event_date
GROUP BY a1.player_id, a1.event_date
ORDER BY a1.player_id, a1.event_date;
```

And, I wrote the following code and got the below result. If one sees the output below, then a1_played looks aligned  and a2_Played contains only 0 and 5 values. I am not able to make out why then are we summing over a2_played

```
SELECT a1.player_id, a1.event_date as a1_Date, a2.event_date as a2_Date,a1.games_played as a1played,a2.games_played as a2played,
SUM(a1.games_played) AS sum_a1,SUM(a2.games_played) AS sum_a2
FROM activity a1, activity a2
WHERE a1.player_id = a2.player_id
AND a1.event_date >=a2.event_date
GROUP BY a1.player_id, a1.event_date
ORDER BY a1.player_id, a1.event_date;
```

| Player_Id | a1_Date | a2_Date | a1_Played | a2_Played | sum_a1_Played | Sum_a2_Played |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2016-03-01 | 2016-03-01 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 2016-05-02 | 2016-03-01 | 6 | 5 | 12 | 11 |
| 1 | 2017-06-25 | 2016-03-01 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 2016-03-02 | 2016-03-02 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2018-07-03 | 2016-03-02 | 5 | 0 | 10 | 5 |

Comment: I've removed the tag spam here. When tagging an rdBMS, please.only tag the one you are *really* using.

Comment: Side note: It's 2022 now (I *almost* said 2021), the ANSI-92 explicit join syntax has been around for 30 years now, you really should adopt it. There is no reason to be using that old 80 implicit join syntax.

Answer (score 3):

If you rewrote your query in your dad's SQL rather than your granddad's SQL, that is with explicit JOINs, the answer would leap out at you.  (Sorry to be snarky, but I personally switched to explicit JOINs in 1994 and never looked back.)

```sql
SELECT a1.player_id, a1.event_date, SUM(a2.games_played) AS games_so_far
  FROM activity a1
  JOIN activity a2     ON a1.player_id = a2.player_id
                      AND a1.event_date >=a2.event_date
 GROUP BY a1.player_id, a1.event_date
 ORDER BY a1.player_id, a1.event_date
```

The `>=` inequality in the second part of the ON clause does the trick. Each successive `event_date` from a1 joins to an ever-increasing number of rows. Then they get summed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, sum(a.games_played) over(partition by player_id order by a.event_date rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as games_played
 from Activity a;
```

Using window function and rolling sum over window of player_id